# Setting Cover and Media in Shopware 6

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6

I am working on custom CLI Product Importer plugin for Shopware, and I am kind of stuck on media part.
So far I have CSV Importer, which works perfectly. I can import all products as well I created Media Importer, that uploads all images to product media directory.
But the thing is, that I don’t know how to make the „bridge“, connection between media repository and product repository to be able to set cover and media(images) for a product

To sum up, my question is, how can I set the cover id? As far as I know, ID comes from product_media table?

Product Mapper

```
{
  "product": {
    "productNumber": "Product Number",
    "name": "Name",
    "active": {
      "key": "Active",
      "type": "bool"
    },
    "media": {
      "map": {
        "fileName": "Media"
      }
    },
    "cover": {
      "map": {
        "mediaId": "Cover"
      }
    },
    "description": "Description",
    "stock": {
      "key": "Stock",
      "type": "int"
    },
```

ProductService

```
    /**
     * @throws Throwable
     */
    public function setProducts(array $rows, Context $context): void
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $this->setProduct($row, $context);
        }
    }

    public function setProduct(array $row, Context $context): void
    {
        try {
            $productId = $this->getId('productNumber', $row['productNumber'], $context);
            if ($productId) {
                $row['id'] = $productId;
                $this->update($row, $context);
            } else {
                $this->create($row, $context);
            }
        } catch (Throwable $throwable) {
            throw $throwable;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`cover` is a `ManyToOneAssociationField` and has a local foreign key with the property name `coverId` you can set directly. The id should be one of a `product_media` entity.

```php
$this->productRepository->update(
    [
        [
            'id' => $productId, 
            'coverId' => $productMediaId,
            'media' => [
                [
                    'id' => $productMediaId,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    $context
);
```

Comment: So right now I have a directory Upload/Media and there are files stores such as ABC01.jpg, ABC02.jpg. What I made, is that Cover name needs to match Product Name. So automatically I am able to upload all files, insert products and it is going to set cover images (So if there is a file named ABC01 it is going to be set as cover for product ABC01. But do you know maybe, what kind of mechanism am I able to use, for assigning multiple pictures for one product? For product ABC01 I want to set cover ABC01, and ABC01_01 as normal media / preview picture?  Thanks for help!